# How to see the textbox text as soon as it changes in another textbox bound with same model property using MVC Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Just for clarity, I have taken the simplified form to understand the behavior:

I have one form in MVC view which is bound with one Model having one property as ReservingPartyName

Suppose there are 2 textboxes as below:

```html
@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.ReservingPartyName)

@Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.ReservingPartyName)
```

You can see that both the textboxes are mapped with model property ReservingPartyName, I want if one of the textbox changes it should automatically change the text in another textbox without jquery.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Prateek

Comment: The obvious question here is, why have you bound two textboxes to the same model property?? What is the purpose behind that?

Comment: Anyway if there is a good reason for that, and you want to solve your problem, then you need some Javascript (you don't need jQuery necessarily, but you will definitely need some JavaScript). You need to handle something like the "input" event on each textbox, get the current value of the textbox and update the other one with it. But don't do this until you're sure you really need two identical textboxes to begin with....

Comment: @Adyson Thanks for your response. Actually the code in post just for understading the implementation. My actual scenario is I have one parent view which has 4 tabs and on 3 tabs there are few input controls but in 4th tab I need to show summary of all the data entered in 3 tabs. I have passed the parent mdel in 4th tab and trying to fetch the values from model for other 3 tabs.

Comment: Should this summary be read-only? If so then you don't need a textbox, just a div or span would be sufficient. Anyway, assuming these tabs are all in the same view, then my point still stands - whether you use an input or a div or a span for the summary, you still need to use some JavaScript to copy the information from the first textbox. You can do it in real time, or you can do it just when the summary tab is opened, it's up to you.

Comment: @Adyson Obviously I am showing the data in summary page in span only. But I need to write extra javascript code to set text in summary page. I am strange why same model is not able to set the text directly just like we do in WPF

Comment: "Obviously I am showing the data in summary page in span only"...ok, so if that's already the case, then the fact  that you have a summary page still doesn't explain why you have got two textboxes?

Comment: _"I am strange why same model is not able to set the text"_ ...because in ASP.NET the C# code (which is what deals with models) only runs on the server, when the view is being created. It does not run in the browser, which is where the user is doing the typing. A web application is a distributed, disconnected client-server application. Anything that happens on the client (i.e. browser) side is not known on the server until a new request is sent to the server. That's why you would need JavaScript - that's the language which runs in the browser and can detect what happens in the browser.

Comment: " so if that's already the case, then the fact that you have a summary page still doesn't explain why you have got two textboxes?": I dont have two textboxes, if you see my post clearly you can see that my intention was to understand the implementation for the behavior when same property is used at more than one time. In my case, in first of 3 tabs I have input controls and in 4th tab i have readonly data for the same controls.

Comment: Sorry if you don't have two textboxes, then why are you asking the question at all? Do you actually have a real problem that you need to solve here? It's still unclear why you would think having two textboxes for the same property was even necessary at all. And since it almost certainly isn't necessary (and you haven't yet provided an explanation to give a use case where it _would_ be necessary), then the question is a little bit pointless.

Comment: I thought you were asking because you'd already implemented the two textboxes for some reason, and were wondering how to keep them in sync, but actually it seems you are asking a theoretical question about a problem which doesn't exist, and is never likely to exist in a sensibly implemented view.

Comment: I don't think its necessary to put down the whole real time scenario over here. What i wanted to understand was how mvc works when using same model property more than one time. This is very well mentioned in the question.Thanks for looking into this question.

Comment: Its not at all a theoretical question only, I have already explained the real time scenario in the comments section that I am using the same model in tab where i am asking for user input and in the tab where i am showing the details user has entered. I am not making any server side call while switching between the tabs.

Comment: by "real-time" I meant the difference between copying the data immediately as the user types each character, as opposed to just getting the final text when the summary tab becomes visible. Those are two different ways to implement it in JavaScript. I didn't mean via calls to the server. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: P.S. It's still really a theoretical question, because having two input fields bound to the same model property is not something anyone would ever do in reality (or at least, not if they designed their view correctly).

Comment: You still did not understand my post. My post simply means how to use same model property more than once with the latest changes, it is no where related to two input fields. Please check the first line of the post it says just for clarity. and while referring to 2 textboxes i have mentioned suppose if this is the case. Hope it clears.

Comment: _"how to use same model property more than once"_ ...there is never any need to do that. There is never any need to define two input elements which are bound to the same property. If you need to display the updated contents of an input element in another place in the page, you can just use JavaScript to copy the data - but that has nothing at all to do with the binding of model properties. You don't have to bind the second location to the model in order to achieve that. HTML/JavaScript knows nothing about your model, it just sees some HTML elements with data in them.